# How to get Mypy working with multiple mixins relying on each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, generic-programming, mypy

Currently in Electrum we use the [`Union` type on `self`](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/c9ede074629a4bbb02f94522a32469d5a5eaeadb/electrum/plugins/hw_wallet/qt.py#L203) to be able to access methods from multiple mixed-in parent classes. For example, `QtPluginBase` relies on being mixed into a subclass of `HW_PluginBase` to work. For example, a valid use is `class TrezorPlugin(QtPluginBase, HW_PluginBase)`.

There is the Qt gui, the Kivy gui, and there is also CLI. Although hardware wallets are not implemented for Kivy, they could be in the future. You can already use them on the CLI.

However there are also multiple hardware wallet manufacturers, all with their own plugins.

Consider Trezor + Qt:

For Qt, we have this class hierarchy:

- `electrum.plugins.hw_wallet.qt.QtPluginBase` used by
- `electrum.plugins.trezor.qt.QtPlugin(QtPluginBase)`

For Trezor, we have:

- `electrum.plugin.BasePlugin` used by
- `electrum.plugins.hw_wallet.plugin.HW_PluginBase(BasePlugin)` used by
- `electrum.plugins.trezor.trezor.TrezorPlugin(HW_PluginBase)`

And to create the actual Qt Trezor plugin:

- `electrum.plugins.trezor.qt.Plugin(TrezorPlugin, QtPlugin)`

The point is that the base gui-neutral plugin will first gain manufacturer-specific methods; then it will gain gui-specific methods.

Aaron (in the comments) suggests that `QtPluginBase` could subclass `HW_PluginBase`, but that would mean that the manufacturer-specific stuff would come after, which means the resulting classes cannot be used by the CLI or Kivy.

Note that both

`electrum.plugins.trezor.trezor.TrezorPlugin(HW_PluginBase)`

and

`electrum.plugins.hw_wallet.qt.QtPluginBase`

rely on `HW_PluginBase`. They can't both subclass it.

So if we avoid mix-ins, then the only alternative would be to either have `QtPluginBase` subclass `TrezorPlugin` (but there are many manufacturers), or `TrezorPlugin` could subclass `QtPluginBase` but then, again, the resulting classes cannot be used by the CLI or Kivy.

I realize that `Union` is an "or", so the hint is indeed not making sense. But there is no `Intersection` type. With Union, most of the PyCharm functionality works.

One thing that would be nice is if `QtPluginBase` could have a type-hint that it subclasses `HW_PluginBase`, but without actually subclassing at runtime.

How could this be typed with Mypy without having to use this hacky `Union` type hint on every method (since every method has `self`)?

Comment: I will try to dig deeper on that, but my first approach would be to create a custom type alias, along with the baseclass: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#type-aliases

Comment: @JanusTroelsen I tried to create an MCVE with your "Union type on self" but I got `error: Item "QtPluginBase" of "Union[QtPluginBase, HW_PluginBase]" has no attribute "keystore_class"`.

Comment: @aaron Is that a bug from Mypy? I see `keystore_class` [defined in HW_PluginBase](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/6b8c447eb90a0a37f7271681e98f319c8178592a/electrum/plugins/hw_wallet/plugin.py#L42), I don't know why Mypy doesn't recognize that?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen It seems correct. `Union` means `or`. `QtPluginBase` doesn't have `keystore_class`. Why doesn't it subclass `HW_PluginBase` if its methods directly depend on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the Protocols added in [PEP-544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) (Python 3.8+), you can define the intersection interface yourself! This also lets you hide implementation details in `ClassA` that you don't want `ClassB` to use.

```
from typing import Protocol

class InterfaceAB(Protocol):
    def method_a(self) -> None: ...
    def method_b(self) -> None: ...

class ClassA:
    def method_a(self) -> None:
        print("a")

class ClassB:
    def method_b(self: InterfaceAB) -> None:
        print("b")
        self.method_a()

# if I remove ClassA here, I get a type checking error!
class AB(ClassA, ClassB): pass

ab = AB()
ab.method_b()

# % mypy --version
# mypy 0.761
# % mypy mypy-protocol-demo.py
# Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Credits to SomberNight/ghost43 for the initial version of this file.

Comment: I like this much better than my own answer! Hint: for python<3.8, there's a backport of protocols in `typing_extensions`, e.g. `if sys.version_info >= (3, 8): from typing import Protocol; else: from typing_extensions import Protocol`.

Answer (score 1):

Since [`mypy` doesn't offer an `Intersection` type yet](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213), you can't type the `self` arg correctly (and the `Union` is not a replacement for that!). What you can do is introducing base classes for mixins for type checking only. This is a trick I often use when working with mixins in Django projects. Example:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .plugin import HW_PluginBase
    _Base = HW_PluginBase
else:
    _Base = object


class QtPluginBase(_Base):
    def load_wallet(self, wallet: 'Abstract_Wallet', window: ElectrumWindow):
        ...
```

You can now drop the explicit typing of `self` since `mypy` can infer all necessary base classes itself.